# GCMBroadcast Receiver getting called 3 times on every notification

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I made a GCMBroadcast Receiver which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}}
```

I am registering it in my Manifest as follows:

```
   <receiver android:name="com.cmm.Services.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.keylessentry.end_user" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.cmm.Services.GCMIntentService" />
```

Every time Server sends me a notification, the receiver is being called 3 times. I am not getting that what mistake I have done.

Comment: Check your server side whether you are sending the message 3 times from server I guess

Comment: It is not your fault sir, GCM does that sometimes. I have experienced this. Same code works fine later.

Comment: @Clairvoyant Thanks. It was in fact server side fault. I was brainstorming on this for 2 days.

Comment: Its my pleasure that i can able solve your problem